# Should I add a mound of concrete on top of existing concrete to direct water away from fence posts?

Tags: concrete, fence

After living in this house 3 years, I realized that our wooden fence, built maybe 8ish years ago, wasn't done as I'd like. 
1: The panels are installed too low, so the bottom of the boards are up to a few inches under ground in places. I'm removing panels and cutting the rotted wood off across the bottom so there will be a few inches of clearance. 
2: The concrete at the base of the posts isn't built up to send water away from the post. It's not even level with the surrounding ground, but is 3-5 inches below the dirt. Is it wise and sufficient to scrape off as much dirt as I can and add a sloping  mound at each post base? 
I'm attaching an image of one I've already done this to, and one which is still undone. There are 20 or 25 posts. 
My mother in law lost an otherwise very solid fence last year because her posts rotted at the bottom, so I would hate to have it happen to me. 
 [image: Here I've cleared dirt down to the top of the existing concrete.][image: Here I've added new concrete on the old, to make a slope for rain to leave the post.]

Answer (score 1):

I do dome the concrete depending where it is at I may make it above ground level , in a small back yard for example I may make the top of the dome at ground level but in a field above ground level because that is easy , I have seen many that were dished holding the water and making a tasty meal for carpenter ants & termites & rot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't consider that important. Any post encased in concrete is perpetually damp anyway. Added concrete will probably crack loose anyway, making it pointless.

Next time dome them or give them a slope, but if you like sod over the concrete (as I do) it doesn't much matter.